# AnkhSVN Upgrade causing problems: Working copy too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I just upgraded to AnkhSVN 2.3.10509.1073 and now if I try to commit via VS2010, I get the error:

> Working copy
>
> 'C:\path\to\build' is too old
>
> (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)

Any idea how I can get this working?

I was previously using Ankh 2.1.10129.  Thank you.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling and re-installing the older version... appears to have worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ankh 2.3 use SVN 1.7 that has a new working copy format. You need to upgrade your working copy manually.

You need to run `svn upgrade` from a command line on your working copy or right click->'Upgrade Working Copy' in AnkhSVN

Comment: AnkhSVN doesn't support 'svnadmin upgrade', but you can just upgrade working copies in AnkhSVN 2.3. It is the first command in +- every context menu when upgrade is necessary.

Comment: TortoiseSVN supports upgrading straight from Windows Explorer.

Comment: In VS2010 right click project -> Subversion -> Working Copy Explorer and in Working Copy Explorer select project/solution -> upgrade working copy should do the trick.

Comment: I'm afraid the "Upgrade working copy" is slightly problematic in the sense it just does not work. It's hard to complain about free software but really there is no warning that upgrading to version 2.3 pretty much invalidates your working copy. I just spent the last two hours getting a fresh new copy from source and copying over the files I had amended since the last check-in. My mistake: don't trust the docs and check everything in before upgrading anything.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo, I run "Upgrade working copy" then try to check in and get the error "Working copy is too old". Tried it on folders, individual files, restarting VS, didn't fix it.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo, clicking the option on the menu displays a window where status is reported on the files it upgrades, but when it's all said and done, the Upgrade Working Copy menu is still there as if the upgrade hadn't happened at all

Comment: 0
down vote
i have upgraded ankhsvn too to 2.5. it asked for upgrade the working copy and i upgraded. Now in visual studio its working fine and showing checked in items, but in windows explorer dowsn't show the tick icon on folders showing checked in or not. I am using tortoisesvn 1.8.